WebSockets message sending order
I am making blocking requests calls in a WebSockets server just to test a thing out, but I experienced a weird behavior.
There is one client connection, sending a single message. The message is processed and the server sends progress messages to the client while handling this message.
Simplified:
async def message_handler(foo, websocket_connection):
    for bar in foo:
        requests.get(bar)
        await websocket_connection.send("request sent")

So I know that requests is blocking the event loop, but since I know that I only have one client sending one message, I would have imagined that it did not matter.
Client side though I am receiving the first "request sent" right away but then the last five at the same time after a longer period.
It helps when I substitute requests with a non-blocking version like aiohttp. But I still have hard time understanding the flow.
I thought that when I am awaiting the websocket.send, then I can assume that the message has been sent when that function returns.
When requests I thought I was blocking the connection handler and the receiving of messages from the client, not the actual sending of messages.
Can someone explain why this message is actually sent to the client when the websocket.send returns?
I assume that what websockets do under the hood is handling sending out messages on another process in the event loop and the actual send function only puts the message on a queue, but then I don't get why the first message is not blocked, only the subsequent.
